# Link "My Workbench" no longer visible

Tags: 7, workbench

I've always used the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) and the [Workbench Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) modules, but recently, the link "My Workbench" in the admin menu has disappeared...

I tried reinstalling the module several times, but no luck there. And all the permissions are checked and double checked, so nothing wrong there.

What else could be the issue?

Comment: Did you change your permissions lately? added new custom Codes/Themes?

Comment: Yes I did change permissions, but with the admin user (uid = 1), I don't see the link either, so there must be something wrong I think as he is the root user.

Comment: Could you change the permissions back and see if it will work again, maybe you did something wrong there

Comment: Are you using Admin Menu module?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have it appear in the admin menu.
You need to give access to:

"Use the administration pages and help"

Because the My Workbench link is child of admin:
/admin/workbench