# Link “My Workbench” is no longer visible

Tags: 7, workbench

I have installed Workbench and the Workbench Moderation modules, but My Workbench(on top with other Administration Menu) link is coming only for when user logged in as Administrator, it is not visible for user with Editor role.
I have given following permissions to Editor
Workbench

```
Administer Workbench settings

For Editor: 
Administer Workbench settings - Yes
Access My Workbench - Yes
```

Comment: try clear cache.

Comment: I have tried after clearing cahce(Configuration -> Development -> Clear All Cache). Do I need to use Flush All Cache -> Administration Menu or both are same?

Comment: did u assign editor role to user?

Comment: yes. I already assigned. Now I have only one link 'Add Content' there at the top. I need My Workbench link too..

Comment: use Flush All Cache -> Administration

Answer (score 2):

I posted an answer on this question:
[Link "My Workbench" no longer visible](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65355/link-my-workbench-no-longer-visible)

In order to have it appear in the admin menu. You need to give access to:

"Use the administration pages and help"

Because the My Workbench link is child of admin: /admin/workbench